# Why is my map not loading

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a map and what I am trying to do is to get somewhat of a table into the info window. I have accomplished that by mixing java-script and php (in which both I am not to all familiar with). So my question is why is my map not displaying? When I go and view the source code everything is there just how I want it, but is something silly causing the map not to display. I have posted the code below hopefully a more skillful eye can catch the problem. Please take it easy on me I have only been coding for about 6 months and still make a lot of mistakes.

So the problem I am having is this portion

```
 "<?php
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($default_properties as $prop_key => $value) {

      ?>"
    '<div class="view-row">'
      '<div class="view-label">'."<?php echo $prop_key?>".'</div>' +;
      '<div class="view-value">'. "<?php echo $value?>".'</div>' +;
    '</div>'; "<?php 

      $cnt++;
    }

    if ($node_id > 0) {

    foreach ($node_values as $prop_key => $value) {


    ?>"
    '<div class="view-row">'
      '<div class="view-label">'."<?php echo $prop_key?>".'</div>' +;
      '<div class="view-value">'. "<?php echo $value?>".'</div>' +;
    '</div>';<?php 

      $cnt++;
    }

    } 

    ?>"
```

I can manipulate the above portion so that the Array loads but then I cannot format it. This way it formats correct but does not load the map. But when I view the source code of the map everything is there! So I am seriously confused.

Full script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();    
    var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();



function initialize() 
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9550040,-77.4045560);
        var settings = 


    //sets the settings of the map

        {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP        
        }

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings); 

        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)   

        if(navigator.geolocation) 
        {    
            browserSupportFlag = true;     
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 

            {       
              initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);      
              map.setCenter(initialLocation);     
            }, function() 

                {       
                    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);     
                });   
        }   

    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation  

        else 
            {     
              browserSupportFlag = false;     
              handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);   
            } 



        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) 
            {     
                if (errorFlag == true) 

                {       
                  alert("Geolocation service failed.");       
                  initialLocation = Virgina;     
                } 
                else 
                {       
                  alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in here.");       
                  initialLocation = '';    
                }     
                  map.setCenter(initialLocation);  
            } 
    }



        // Takes an address and places a marker in google maps

function codeAddress() 

    {     
        var address = "<?php echo $node_address?>";
        var description = "<?php echo $node_title?>";
        var property = "<?php echo $default_properties?>";
        var values = "<?php echo $node_values?>";

        <?php
            $js_array = json_encode($end_node_addresses);
            echo "var end_addresses = ". $js_array . ";\n";
        ?>

        var image = "<?php echo $entity_icon?>";


        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
        {       
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {         
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location); 

                var contentString = '<div id="contentmarker">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?php echo $node_title?></h2>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p> Is a <?php echo $entity_name?> located in<?php echo $node_address?></br> "<?php
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($default_properties as $prop_key => $value) {

      ?>"
    '<div class="view-row">'
      '<div class="view-label">'."<?php echo $prop_key?>".'</div>' +;
      '<div class="view-value">'. "<?php echo $value?>".'</div>' +;
    '</div>'; "<?php 

      $cnt++;
    }

    if ($node_id > 0) {

    foreach ($node_values as $prop_key => $value) {


    ?>"
    '<div class="view-row">'
      '<div class="view-label">'."<?php echo $prop_key?>".'</div>' +;
      '<div class="view-value">'. "<?php echo $value?>".'</div>' +;
    '</div>';<?php 

      $cnt++;
    }

    } 

    ?>"     <b></b></p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                {
                    content: contentString
                });


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({            
                map: map,             
                position: results[0].geometry.location, 
                icon: image,
                title: address
                });  

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            } 

            else 
            {        
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);       
            }     
        });  

        var title_vars = end_addresses;

        for (i = 0; i < end_addresses.length; i++)
        {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': end_addresses[i]}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {       
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                var contentString = '<div id="contentmarker">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?php echo $node_title?></h2>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p> Is located in "<?php echo $js_array?>"</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({            
                                    map: map,             
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    icon: image,
                                    title: title_vars.shift(),
                                    });  
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });     
                                } 

                                else 
                                {        
                                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);       
                                }     
                            }); 
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: What are all the single and double quotes around your code ?

Comment: I was told I needed them. Somewhere I think that is the problem I just cant find where.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go ahead and remove those quotes:

```
<?php
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($default_properties as $prop_key => $value) {

?>
    <div class="view-row">
      <div class="view-label"><?php echo $prop_key?></div>
      <div class="view-value"><?php echo $value?></div>
    </div>
<?php 
      $cnt++;
    }

    if ($node_id > 0) {

    foreach ($node_values as $prop_key => $value) {

?>
    <div class="view-row">
      <div class="view-label"><?php echo $prop_key; ?></div>
      <div class="view-value"><?php echo $value; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php 

      $cnt++;
    }

    } 
?>
```

Without breaking out of PHP:

```
<?php
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($default_properties as $prop_key => $value) {

    echo '<div class="view-row"><div class="view-label">' . 
        $prop_key . '</div><div class="view-value">' . 
        $value . '</div></div>';

      $cnt++;
    }

    if ($node_id > 0) {

    foreach ($node_values as $prop_key => $value) {

    echo '<div class="view-row"><div class="view-label">' . 
        $prop_key . '</div><div class="view-value">' . 
        $value . '</div></div>';

      $cnt++;
    }

    } 
?>
```

Comment: Even when I remove the quotes, just like you have in the section without breaking out of PHP I still get the white screen. But I can do this and get the map to populate but the formatting is note right.    <?php
 $cnt = 0;
 foreach ($default_properties as $prop_key => $value) {

   echo $prop_key
   echo $value 
    $cnt++;
 }
 
 if ($node_id > 0) {
 
 foreach ($node_values as $prop_key => $value) {
   echo $prop_key 
   echo $value  

   $cnt++;
 }
 
 } 
 
 ?>

Comment: @user1639669 Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to your script and see what it says.

Comment: I have error reporting turned on, and when I have a error it will usually tell me whats wrong as to why the page did not load. In this case it's telling. Its just not loading the page and the source code tells me that the piece of code is there and working fine. i am lost here and don't know what else to do or another way to do it.

Comment: I was able to get it working last night with a few tweaks of the second code. The first one breaks the syntax of the script at the end. I still have to mess with the alignment it displays the first value correct then puts all the other ones under the prop. I want to show you a screen shot email me at IGDMT@gmail.com and I can send you a screen shot of how its formatting it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user1639669 I tried e-mailing you but the address does not work.

Comment: I do apologize I missed typed it. IGDMTBAH@gmail.com